# Diffeomorphism with prescribed behaviour

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

If $\gamma$ and $\eta$ are two smooth curves in a smooth manifold $M$, is it possible to find a diffeomorphism of $M$ such that $f \circ \gamma = \eta$? What if one removes the assumption of smoothness, working with topological manifolds (or even plain topological spaces) and homeomorphisms?

(Later edit: Argghh! I apologize, I forgot to specify: both curves do not have self-intersections and are homotopic.)

Comment: There must be some hypotheses on the curve: a figure 8 and a O are not going to be equivalent.

Comment: Even for simple closed curves you have at least to require something about their same free homotopy classes (e.g. there's no way you can move a conctractible curve to a meridian of a torus)

Comment: Do you know about knots in 3-space? Are these all equivalent?

Comment: Apologies, it's late night here. The question has been edited and hypotheses added.

Comment: Homotopic isn't enough: As Misha remarks all knots are homotopic, but they certainly cannot be conjugated one another. In general looking into knot theory is a good way to test for pathologies in this kind of questions.

Comment: And the question becomes kind of trivial if you take into account knots.  If one demands the knots are isotopic, then the diffeomorphism $f$ will exist and be isotopic to the identity.

Comment: @DenisNardin: I'm afraid I don't follow you here: "all knots are homotopic". Unless the ambient space is simply-connected, your example above shows the contrary.

Comment: @RyanBudney: My curves cannot be closed, so knots are ruled out. Can you give me a (bibliographical) hint about why the required diffeomorphism exists and why it is isotopic to the identity? This result is precisely what I was hoping for.

Comment: @AlexM. I was thinking of knots in $S^3$ (that's where classical knot theory lives). The knots are obviously all nullhomotopic but they often cannot be swapped by a diffeomorphism because e.g. the respective complements are not homotopic. I think it is a theorem of Waldhausen that if the complements have isomorphic fundamental group then the knots are isotopic. If you want I can chase around a more precise reference.

Comment: Hi Alex.  If your definition of "curve" is embeddings of say $[0,1]$ in a manifold, then the result follows in dimensions $n \geq 2$ by the isotopy extension theorem, together with the observation that the unit tangent bundle of a connected manifold is connected.  In dimension $n=1$ the diffeomorphism would not always be isotopic to the identity, as the corresponding unit tangent bundle is not connected. The proof is primarily the *isotopy extension theorem * whose proof is an ODEs result and can be found in Hirsch's textbook on differential topology.

Comment: If your definition of "curve" allows for embeddings of $\mathbb R$ into the manifold then one would also have to take into account the behaviour of the curve at infinity. The answer would be a little more complicated.

Comment: Alex M. You should edit your question to make it clear what exactly are you asking: if your curves are not assumed to be closed then they are automatically homotopic.

Comment: @Misha: Yesterday I have edited it and specified that my curves do not have self-intersections. This means that in particular they cannot be closed, thus ruling knots out of discussion.

Comment: And why then did you add the assumption that they are homotopic? Note that topological knits are also regarded as curves without self intersections. What you really need us to define what you mean by a "curve".

Comment: @Misha: Because it was not (and still isn't) obvious to me that two simple copies of $[0,1]$ are automatically homotopic (I'm not a topologist, by the way). Should I understand that they are?

Comment: @RyanBudney: Right now I'm taking a look at Hirsch's book. Still, it's not clear to me why in dimension $\leq 3$ two homotopic copies of $[0,1]$ should be isotopic. Apparently, such a result is guaranteed to be valid in dimension $\geq 4$ (see exercise 10 after chapter 8, part 1, page 183, 5th edition).

Comment: Hi Alex, there is precisely one isotopy-class of smoooth embedding of $[0,1]$ into a manifold if and only if the unit tangent bundle of that manifold is connected.  This follows from the isotopy extension theorem in a standard way.  For manifolds of dimension $n \geq 2$ their unit tangent bundles are connected if and only if the manifold is connected.  For $n=1$ the unit tangent bundle is never connected.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Thank you for your answer, it put me on the right track. Please notice that your answer is a special case of theorem 3.1 (page 185) in Hirsch's book. He does not use the unit tangent bundle (which would require a Riemann metric), instead working in $GL(n)$ (which is disconnected when $n=1$). If you wish to publish your comment as an answer, I shall gladly "accept" it.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, you spend a lot of time editing old, inactive posts, only to add some tags. This is not useful. If you didn't know, every such edit pushes the edited post to the main page of MO, which in turn pushes some new post out of the main page (because the number of posts displayed on the main page is fixed); as a consequence, new posts stay less time on the main page, therefore are less visible, which should not happen.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you for your  comment. First the  word "old" is  a  relative  word. second the  percentage of  my revision of  "old" post over all my MO  activities is  a very  "little" number. However, i  believe  that some times an old post is  interesting which is  not well taged, so  it is  worthy of  revision. Any  way  this  post  of  you is  realy  a  question in the area of  diff. topology.May  be  I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your definition of "curve" is embeddings of say $[0,1]$ in a manifold, then the result follows in dimensions $n\geq 2$ by the isotopy extension theorem, together with the observation that the unit tangent bundle of a connected manifold is connected. In dimension $n=1$ the diffeomorphism would not always be isotopic to the identity, as the corresponding unit tangent bundle is not connected. The proof is primarily the *isotopy extension theorem* whose proof is an ODEs result and can be found in Hirsch's textbook on differential topology.

Some more details: there is precisely one isotopy-class of smoooth embedding of $[0,1]$ into a manifold if and only if the unit tangent bundle of that manifold is connected. This follows from the isotopy extension theorem in a standard way. For manifolds of dimension $n \geq 2$ their unit tangent bundles are connected if and only if the manifold is connected. For $n=1$ the unit tangent bundle is never connected.

Answer (score 6):

Just to finish this thing off:

The following are equivalent:

1. A smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ satisfies the property that for any two smooth homotopic 1-dimensional knots $K, K'$ in $M$, the pairs $(M, K), (M,K')$ are diffeomorphic .
2. $n\ne 3$.

The only nontrivial case is when $n=2$, it goes back to Dehn and Nielsen, see Andy's answer.

Answer (score 5):

In the case that $M=\Sigma$ is a closed, oriented surface, this question has a rather complete answer; Farb and Margalit call it the "change of coordinates principle" in "The Primer on Mapping Class Groups."  It says that given $\alpha, \beta$ two simple, homotopically non-trivial, non-separating (i.e. $\Sigma\backslash \alpha$ is connected) closed curves, there exists a diffeomorphism $f:\Sigma\rightarrow \Sigma$ such that $f(\alpha)=\beta.$  You can find this discussion starting on page 40 of the Primer.  The proof is a pretty simple idea, you cut two copies of $\Sigma,$ one along $\alpha$ and one along $\beta,$ and then use the classification of surfaces to a obtain a diffeomorphism between these cut open surfaces (which are now surfaces with boundary) which is the identity on the boundary.  Then you re-glue and obtain a diffeomorphism of $\Sigma$ which does what you want by construction.  This can be extended to $k$-tuples of simple curves satisfying some simple homological hypotheses (again see the Primer).